# R markdown / bookdown - how to display keywords below an abstract?

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

I defined keywords in the .Rmd file, but they are not visible in the output PDF.

---

**Current Output**

[image: output without keywords]

---

**Expected results**

[image: expected results with keywords]

---

**Current .Rmd**

First lines of .Rmd file looks as follows:

````
---
title: "No keywords within the output file"
abstract: "This is sample text for abstract. Generally speaking, I would like to show keywords list below an abstract (as in case of the linked example)"
keywords: "keywordA, keywordB"
author: "Mateusz Kędzior"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: yes
    toc: false
base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Elsevier article

This is an R Markdown document.

I'm trying to prepare an Elsevier article.
````

Comment: It would be nice if you gave the expected example output inside the question instead of forcing readers to chase after non-clickable links and importing project templates into overleaf. Generally speaking, you should limit your question to the information that’s necessary and not clutter it with irrelevant details.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it will be easier to provide full output, so that it will be fully reproducible. I amended my question.

Comment: @matandked: And how you got rid of the "0." leading numbering of all your subtitles/sections? [because it is a single document]

Comment: Since I have "0" in my section numbering example output, I haven't tried to remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if `base_format` is actually doing any work in your example (the output looks the same with and without `base_format`).  Since `base_format` is an argument to `pdf_book`, consider changing your YAML header to

```
---
title: "No keywords within the output file"
author: 
- name: "Mateusz Kędzior"
abstract: "This is sample text for abstract. Generally speaking, I would like to show keywords list below an abstract (as in case of the linked example)"
keywords: "keywordA, keywordB"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: yes
    toc: false
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
---
```

which gives you the following output:

[image]

---

Alternatively, add keywords to the abstract:

```
    abstract: "This is sample text for abstract. Generally speaking, I would like
 to show keywords list below an abstract (as in case of the linked example) \\par
 \\textbf{Keywords:} a, b"
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but...generally speaking I have much more complex document. Once I changed heading according to your suggestion, document was unable to compile (because of the polish letter "ł" in caption of the one of the figures)

Comment: Once I removed "ł" from caption, I've also noticed that in output .tex file "\citep{PositionInBibFile}" has been replaced by "(Someone, 2012)"

Comment: And instead of including bibliography by "\bibliography{bibliography.bib}" it just includes all bibliography positions in output .tex file

Comment: OK, I would suggest that you open up new questions for these other problems (or edit your minimal working example for these complications). SO Q&A works best when each question is a specific problem, rather than a bundle of problems.

Comment: You're correct, I think that I will need to prepare different question and minimal working example. Because...well I also discovered that there's also equation problem as well (after changing header) although I'm referencing them according to https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations

Comment: Regarding **this** question - is it possible to add keywords in less elegant way, so that I will be still able to use pdf_document2 (some workaround to insert keywords into abstract section)?

Comment: I prepared new example and asked different question as you suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312601/r-markdown-bookdown-how-to-switch-to-rticles

Comment: The solution above uses `\\par` to insert a line break. That didn't work for me with the `bookdown::pdf_document2` format but I was able to use `\newline \newline` following abstract and then `Keywords: ...` on a second line. NOTE: start each new line with two blank spaces or things get wonky.