# R markdown / bookdown - how to switch to rticles?

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

**Input data**

I prepared an example Rmd file with references to figure, table and equation, setting as an output 'bookdown::pdf_document2'. It compiles without errors to PDF.

I placed it on dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zmu0a4wq95ywssv/AAD-nHlkDiLknLk2NVR4Xup3a?dl=0

---

**Question**

Now I wish to set as an output format 'rticles::elsevier_article'

How can I do that?

**Issue**

When I change output line from:
bookdown::pdf_document2
to
rticles::elsevier_article

I'm receiving an error message.

Even if I remove other parameters from output:

[image: TriedToSwitch]

I still receive an error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accented characters when input "as is" do not appear to behave well with `elsevier_article`.  See suggestions below.

---

#### Bare-bones document

Here is a bare-bones document using `rticles::elsevier_article`:

```
---
title: "Sample document"
author: 
  - name: "Mateusz Kędzior"
    affiliation: Some Institute of Technology
    email: Mateusz@example.com
    footnote: Corresponding Author
  - name: Żąćł Źęń    
csl: https://www.zotero.org/styles/geoderma
output:
  rticles::elsevier_article:
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
keywords: keywordA, keywordB
abstract: This is a sample abstract \newline This is the second line of abstract.
---

Hello world.
```

which renders with no complaints:

[image]

---

#### Reference with accents

Now, we wish to add a reference with accents. We follow the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-%C3%A4-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography. I imported your bibliography into Zotero, and then exported the item with a "Central European (ISO)" encoding (not UTF-8) to obtain

```
@article{kedzior_this_2018,
    title = {This is sample title only {\k A} {\L }},
    volume = {99},
    url = {http://megooglethat.com/},
    journal = {Some journal},
    author = {K{\k e}dzior, Mateusz and {\'Z}{\k e}{\'n}, {\.Z}{\k a}{\'c}{\l }},
    year = {2018},
    keywords = {keywordC},
    pages = {21 -- 31}
}
```

The R Markdown document now becomes

```
---
title: "Sample document"
author: 
  - name: "Mateusz Kędzior"
    affiliation: Some Institute of Technology
    email: Mateusz@example.com
    footnote: Corresponding Author
  - name: Żąćł Źęń    
csl: https://www.zotero.org/styles/geoderma
output:
  rticles::elsevier_article:
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
biblio-files: bibliography2.bib
keywords: keywordA, keywordB
abstract: This is a sample abstract \newline This is the second line of abstract.
---

## Citations and references

Let me cite an article: [@kedzior_this_2018]

# References
```

I then `knit`ed this in RStudio, but realised that I had to get the `tex` output and rebuild it (outside of RStudio) to get the desired output
[image]

---

#### Other problems

For accented characters in figure captions, encode them accordingly (as with the bibliography).  You may find http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/latex-symbols-converter helpful.  In addition, to the best of my knowledge `bookdown` style cross-referencing does not work with `rticles`. If you have follow-up questions, you may get more helpful answers if you break your question down into smaller chunks.

Comment: "There are many problems with the R Markdown document" --> I think that this part of your answer suggest the reader that my document is not working at all. Which is not true, it compiles **without** errors when you set as an output pdf_document2. I think that if the "accented characters" are not the main problem, but basically whole document should be significantly changed it will be better to simply answer that rticles is **not** compatible with pdf_document2.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited my answer to clarify.  I don't know if `rticles`is necessarily incompatible with `pdf_document2`. But it's true that the bibliography and captions need to be encoded appropriately when the Elsevier template is used.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer. I remember that when I had issue with accented characters and preparing article, I used some library in my LaTeX document directly to add support to UTF-8 characters... But know, I wish to prepare all my work directly in Rmd

Answer (score 1):

I've added a bit of updated material to the commenthttps://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/92#issuecomment-402784283 where it states (may be updated):

```
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
    number_sections: yes
```

such that the way I've had this work is using `pdf_book` versus `pdf_document2`:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
    number_sections: yes
```

This allows for figure and table referencing within an `rticles` document.